# Marshalling pointer to array P/Invoke

Tags: c#, arrays, .net-core, pinvoke, marshalling

I am wrapping a shared object library `(FFTW)` in `.NET` Core using `P/Invoke`. `FFTW` needs to allocate memory potentially aligned on particular boundaries, so I need to use its memory allocation routine. Ideally, I would like to avoid creating a separate chunk of memory in a managed array and copying the data across on every use. Ideally, the array is created to point to the already allocated memory. Is this possible, or should I give up and take the performance hit of a copy?

Comment: The easiest answer is: use `unsafe` code. But, it has some drawbacks, and depending on how you want to expose the library, you can also use `IntPtr` everywhere and use `Marshal` class helpers. Or use copy and measure if it's really a problem. Difficult to say w/o some end-to-end code (library + caller) sample that you envision.

Comment: You can't control the alignment of the managed array data at all, 4 in 32-bit mode and 8 in 64-bit mode.  Also the reason that SIMD code in .NET is pretty limited.  Not that much to worry about btw, the FT is a lot more expensive than the copying.

Comment: @SimonMourier no, I strongly disagree: the answer here is `Memory<T>` / `Span<T>` - which **explicitly by design** unifies the memory model between arrays and pointers

Comment: @MarcGravell - you're strongly right, but this is strongly quite recent (.NET core 2.1), and Microsoft hasn't strongly even finished the doc as of today: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.memory-1?view=netcore-2.1

Comment: I have been for two years working at a company where we always seem to be on the bleeding edge of Microsoft's .NET related features, so I am used to bad docs and shifting technologies. This question is hobby project related, and yet I find myself again on the bleeding edge of .NET Core.

Comment: @SimonMourier no, span is available for much wider surfaces than that; I *think* it is available as far back as .NET Standard 1.1 and .NET 4.5; it works *better* in .NET Core 2.1, due to JIT improvements (and the 2-field vs 3-field implementation), but it is *available* much more widely.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can't create an *array* that points to unmanaged memory that has been allocated by an external memory manager. You can, however, create a `Span<T>` or a `Memory<T>` that does, which give you a *very similar API* and means you don't need `unsafe` at any point afterwards. Note that to be able to store it anywhere, it needs to be a `Memory<T>` (`Span<T>` is a `ref struct`) - but a `Memory<T>` is essentially just an on-demand span provider - when you want the span, call `.Span` on your `Memory<T>`.

Now; there isn't a `Memory<T>` for dealing with raw pointers that ships out of the box, but it is simple to write one. Or you can just use [this one I wrote earlier](https://github.com/mgravell/Pipelines.Sockets.Unofficial/blob/master/src/Pipelines.Sockets.Unofficial/UnsafeMemory.cs) (a `MemoryManager<T>` is an abstraction that can be used to implement custom `Memory<T>` instances, which can then provide a `Span<T>` when needed).

Usage:

```
int* ptr = ...
int len = ...

var memory = new UnmanagedMemoryManager<int>(ptr, len).Memory;
// (I should probably add a helper method for that!)
```

which gives you a `Memory<int>` that you can store in fields etc; then to work with it, you want the span:

```
var span = _memory.Span;
span[42] = 119; // etc
```

You can also do things like coerced type conversions over spans, allowing them to do most of the same things pointers can do (i.e. in the same way that you can force an `int*` to be a `byte*`, you can convert a `Span<int>` into a `Span<byte>` *over the same memory* - not a copy).

Comment: This looks like a very good answer. Thank you! I am going to try and test before I accept any answer.

Comment: Tested Span<T> and it accomplishes my goals. Thank you.