# c# ReadOnlyMemory from pointer

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, pinvoke, unsafe

Hi there I have a c native library that is returning me json as char*. What I would like to do in c# is to use this pointer and write it straight to the

```
this.ControllerContext.HttpContext.Response.BodyWriter;
```

I'm able to create ReadOnlySpan from the ptr but as far as I can tell PipeWriter only accepts `ReadOnlyMemory<byte>` which does not have a constructor from IntPtr. Is there a way to create `ReadOnlyMemory<byte>` from IntPtr or some other way to writer my string from native library withou copying it one extra time?

Comment: How large do you expect the string to be? Premature optimization is the root of all evil...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your answers but none of them was without extra copy. I was finally figure it out so in case somebody struggle with it, here is the solution.

So the only way I as able to achieve this is like.

```
 await Response.StartAsync(HttpContext.RequestAborted);
 var dest = Response.BodyWriter.GetMemory((int)jsonLen).Pin();
 unsafe { memcpy(dest.Pointer), srcPtr, srcLen); }
 Response.BodyWriter.Advance(srcLen);
 await Response.BodyWriter.FlushAsync(HttpContext.RequestAborted);
```

Comment: That really really looks like it's doing a copy. It's an unsafe copy, which I suppose might be faster, but it's not without copy.

Comment: Code on line 3 seems broken.

Answer (score 3):

This answer provides a solution that does not need to copy the entire buffer:
[Marshalling pointer to array P/Invoke](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51568009/marshalling-pointer-to-array-p-invoke)

TL;DR: Take [UnmanagedMemoryManager](https://github.com/mgravell/Pipelines.Sockets.Unofficial/blob/master/src/Pipelines.Sockets.Unofficial/UnsafeMemory.cs) from Pipelines.Sockets.Unofficial by Marc Gravell.

```
int* ptr = ...
int len = ...

var memory = new UnmanagedMemoryManager<int>(ptr, len).Memory;
```

Unfortunately, you still need to allocate the MemoryManager (it must be a class, not a struct).

Comment: OP has moved on, but your answer looks spot on.

Answer (score 0):

I glad if this could speed up and match to what you wants.

```
namespace Helper
{
    using System;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

    public static class CStringMapper
    {
        // convert unmanaged c string to managed c# string
        public string toCSharpString(char* unmanaged_c_string)
        {
             return Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi((IntPtr)unmanaged_c_string);
         }

         // Free unmanaged c pointer
         public void free(char* unmanaged_c_string)
         {
             Marshal.FreeHGlobal((IntPtr)unmanaged_c_string);
         }
     }
}
```

Usage:

```
 using Helper;

 /* generate your unmanaged c string here */

 try
 {
     // eg. char* OO7c = cLibFunc();
     string cSharpString = CStringMapper.toCSharpString(OO7c);
 } 
 finally
 {
     // Make sure to  freeing the pointer
     CStringMapper.free(OO7c);
 }
```

Comment: Hi thank you very much for your answer but PtrToStringAnsi actually copies the string so not something I want :/

Comment: You are welcome. It is no copy the string, but it convert from c string (char*) into c# string object. But if you didn't need c# string, you must generate serialization for each byte (data) from pointer offset.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe use something like this?

```
public class Utility
{
    public System.ReadOnlyMemory<T> ConvertToReadOnlyMemory(System.ReadOnlySpan<T> input) {
        var tmp = new System.Memory<T>();
        input.CopyTo(tmp.Span);
        return (System.ReadOnlyMemory<T>)tmp;
    }
}
```

However, I think this will involve completely copying the stream into heap storage, which is probably not what you want...